# Plotting Matrix versus Matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix, matlab

So I recently started using Mathematica and I haven't been able to figure out how to simply **plot elements of one matrix versus another matrix** which are **not directly related** or are **not a function of each other**. The way I understand **Plot** in **Mathematica** is that it can only plot functions.

For Eg: Consider 2 matrices

```
a1 = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 1}, {j, 100}]
b1 = Table[Subscript[b, i, j], {i, 1}, {j, 100}]
```

Assume through the main code body, all the elements of both the matrices have been filled. Also its important to remember that **both the matrices are not related**. So how to go about plotting the elements of matrix a1 versus elements of matrix b1?

The same requirement is very simple in **matlab**:

```
plot(a1,b1)
```

Comment: From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html): "If `X` and `Y` are both matrices, then they must have equal size. The `plot` function plots columns of `Y` versus columns of `X`." So, just use `ListPlot[]`/`ListLinePlot[]` along with a judicious use of `Transpose[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = Table[j^2, {j, 1, 25}];
b = Table[Log@j, {j, 1, 25}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{a, b}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is that in my case a and b have already stored values from the results of other functions and are not functions of j itself. How do you write the code for that?

Comment: `a` and `b` in my example are arbitrary lists of numbers. You can use imported lists like `a=Import["file path"] `. However, let's read help info about data import to prevent further technical questions..